# How can I set variable in the path of ImageField of Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my `models.py` :

```
class Group_Photo(models.Model):

    group_id = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/image/group/" + group_id + "/")
```

I'd like to upload images to a directory which is for a group.
For example, if the `group_id = 3`,

`upload_to="static/image/group/3/"`

How should I do?

Sorry, this is the error.

> File "/models.py", line 161, in Group_Photo
>       photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/image/group/" + group_id + "/") TypeError: Can't convert 'ForeignKey' object to str
>   implicitly

Comment: does this code generate an error? what does it output when you try to run your code?

Comment: @Renier Sorry, I forgot to write the Error. I added.

Comment: @someone who said "no you cannot" If I cannot upload images in several directories, do I have to upload only in one directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `upload_to` argument can be a function, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

```
def group_based_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return "image/group/{}/{}".format(instance.group.id, filename)

class Group_Photo(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=group_based_upload_to)
```

The function takes two arguments - instance of the model to which the file is being attached and the original name of the file. It has to return a relative path under witch the file will be saved. It will be appended to the path defined in the `MEDIA_ROOT` setting.

The example above uses directories based on group's numeric id. You can obviously use other fields, for example to use the slug (if it has one) just replace `instance.group.id` with `instance.group.slug`.

Comment: Thank you very much. My Japanese document doesn't mention about that. I will try that now.

Comment: Thank you. When I started with runserver, no error occured. I will implement upload form later.